# Is there a cable release that is compatible with both the 40D and the 70D?

Tags: shutter-release, cables

I'm looking for an inexpensive cable release for my Canon EOS 40D. However, I plan on upgrading to a 70D somewhat soon. This is why I've been looking for a cable release that is compatible with both the 40D and the 70D. However, I haven't found a single product that lists both camera models in their list of supported cameras. Is the technology/jack for those fundamentally different? Or have I just not been looking in the right places?

Comment: Do they both support infrared release? If yes, would that be an option?

Comment: @MirekE I don't think the 40D has that kind of fancy functionality, it's a quite old model

Comment: I don't know about the 40D, but it was on the Rebel XT, I still have the remote and it works on my 7D as well.

Comment: Right, it apparently does not have IR sensor. Cheaper and older cameras apparently had it, though... http://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/E40D/E40DA.HTM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 40D cable remote uses what Canon calls the N3 connector, whereas the 70D uses the E3 connector. The E3 connector is just Canon's name for the [subminiature 3/32" (2.5mm) 3-conductor TRS audio connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)#Modern_connectors).

The N3 connector is just a 3-conductor connector as well (but I believe it is proprietary and only used by Canon).

- If you have a cable release for the 70D, you can get a simple [E3F-N3M adapter](https://amzn.com/B0079WLI3A) to use the cable on your 40D.
- If you have a cable release for the 40D, you can get a simple [N3F-E3M adapter](https://amzn.com/B0079WIITW) to use the cable on your 70D.

Comment: Are there also adapters that do the opposite? Because for now I'm going to get a cable release with a timer functionality  ([this one](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B008BZKKBA/)) for my 40D ...

Comment: Thanks, I have already ordered the cable release above though ^^ Not sure yet when I will get the newer body, and once I do I'll give my 40D back to my father (*technically* it's his), maybe I'll just give him the cable release as well and get a newer one instead. I wanted a simpler one anyway

Answer (score 2):

They're physically different.

The 70D is the audio-jack style connector, while the 40D has the square, stubby connector (see, I know my technical words!)

- [This is the 70D connector](https://store.canon.co.uk/canon-rs-60e3-remote-switch/2469A002/).
- [This is the 40D connector](https://store.canon.co.uk/canon-rs-80n3-remote-switch/2476A001/?nav=accessories%2Ccameraaccessories%2Cother).
- [You can buy a converter / adapter](https://store.canon.co.uk/canon-ra-n3-remote-switch-adapter/2441A001/?nav=accessories%2Ccameraaccessories%2Cother).

Don't buy any of them from the Canon site (far too expensive), buy a 3rd party version from Amazon or similar, just check the reviews.